# Поиск userid в json зная username на js

Tags: javascript, json, postman

мои познания в  js равны 0. Вот собственно вопрос. Есть api запрос (https://social.krotovqa.com/api/user/all) который возвращает список всех юзеров как на js найти id  зная username и запихнуть id в переменную для дальнейшего использования. Документация https://social.krotovqa.com/swagger/ других способов найти userid я не нашел.
[image: postman]

Comment: Много текста - мало сути. Просто предоставьте пример структуры данных и скажите что должна возвращать функция, которая эту структуру принимает.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name1 = pm.environment.get("name");
var json = pm.response.json().filter(h => h.username == name1)[0].id;
pm.environment.set("id", json);
```